# how to change a empty toolbar present in main_activity.xml file with home_toolbar.xml on clicking a specific fragment. Please help, I'm new to android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

[My main activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77HxG.png)

[Activity.xml File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eYo3.png)

[This is my Home Fragment.java File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGNWq.png)

[I want to load this toolbar inside my main activity  default toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Oyfr.png)

Comment: Please repost the Image in a proper understandable format. You can directly attach the image here instead of providing image links.

Comment: I think it's more understandable now sir, please give it a look.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if i get it what do you mean, but if i understood it should be better to place the toolbar inside the fragment and in the default toolbar you can take that off in the manifest archive.

> android:theme="@style/Theme.Application.NoActionBar

So in each fragment, you will have to put another toolbar if you needed

Creating Contextual Menus
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus

Comment: I already did that sir, It's that I want to change the whole toolbar when clicked on a home button(one of the bottom navigation buttons).

Comment: I see, Hum i think it's the "Contextual Action Mode in Android Studio" that you are looking for, there is a lot of tutorials, take a look at youtube, if you didn't learn, i'll give try to do for you.